# Solve in $\mathbf{N}$ the equation $9x^2+p=y^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions, square-numbers, pell-type-equations

In these days, I have been trying to solve this problem:

> Let $p \in \mathbf{N}$ a positive large integer ($> 10^9$). Find all $x, y \in\mathbf{N}$ such that:
> $$9x^2+p=y^2$$

The first approach that I have tried is the following. We know that:
$$(t+n)^2-t^2=t^2+2\cdot t \cdot n +n^2-t^2=2\cdot t \cdot n +n^2$$
Also, we can build every possible square $w_n$ greater than $p$ in this way:
$$w_n=\left\lfloor\sqrt{p}\right\rfloor^2+2\cdot \left\lfloor\sqrt{p}\right\rfloor \cdot n +n^2 = \left(n+\left\lfloor\sqrt{p}\right\rfloor^2\right)^2$$
For example, let $p=5$. Follows that: $w_1=\left(1+\left\lfloor\sqrt{5}\right\rfloor^2\right)^2=9$, $w_2=\left(2+\left\lfloor\sqrt{5}\right\rfloor^2\right)^2=16$ and so on.

Now, using this idea and applying to the first equation:
$$9x^2=\left(n+\left\lfloor\sqrt{p}\right\rfloor^2\right)^2-p$$
I am not allowed to apply Pell's equation because $9=3^2$ and calcultaing $\Delta$ in $x$ doesn't help anymore.

Another approach is based on Pell's equation. I thought to express $9x^2=8x^2+x^2$ and then:
$$8x^2+x^2+p=y^2\leftrightarrow 8x^2+p=y^2-x^2\leftrightarrow (y^2-x^2)-8x^2=p \leftrightarrow u^2-8x^2=p$$
But then, in order to generate all the solutions, I have to guess the first one (or one of them) that is pretty complicated for big $p$.

So, how can we do that? Are there any other solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128452/discussion-between-spectre-and-matteo).

Comment: If $p\equiv0,9,27\pmod{36}$ then finding all such $x$ and $y$ is equivalent to factoring $p$. If $p\equiv2\pmod{3}$ or $p\equiv3,6\pmod{9}$ or $p\equiv2\pmod{4}$ then there is no solution, or equivalently if
$$p\equiv2,3,5,6,8,11,12,14,15,17,18,20,21,23,24,26,29,30,32,33,35\pmod{36}.$$ That leaves $p\equiv1\pmod{3}$ with $p\not\equiv2\pmod{4}$, or equivalently
$$p\equiv1,4,7\pmod{12}.$$

Comment: @Servaes: so, if $p\equiv1,4,7\pmod{12}$ what can we do?

Comment: If $p\equiv4\pmod{12}$ then every solution $(x,y)$ is of the form $(2x',2y')$ where $(x',y')$ is a solution for $p'=\tfrac p4$. So you can simply reduce to the case where $p\equiv1,7\pmod{12}$, i.e. $p\equiv1\pmod{6}$, as there are no solutions if $p\equiv2\pmod{4}$. For $p\equiv1\pmod{6}$ I'm not sure yet.

Comment: @Matteo I have completed my answer; the case $p\equiv1\pmod{6}$ is also equivalent to factoring $p$.

Answer (score 7):

First, reformulate the problem as the following:

$$
y^2 - 9x^2 = p \Rightarrow(y-3x)(y+3x)= p
$$

Now, for any given $p$, find its prime factors. Then, for any 2-partitions of them, solve a simple equation system.

To simplify some cases, suppose $p$ is factorized to $p_1 \times p_2$. Now, solve the following system:

$$
y-3x = p_1
$$
$$
y+3x = p_2
$$

So, $y = \frac{p_1 + p_2}{2}$, and $x = \frac{p_2 - p_1}{6}$. It gives us a heuristic to find potential answers more quickly.  $p_2$ is in the form of $6k + p_1$.

Comment: I think you misread the question.. it was $9x^2 + p = y^2$

Comment: @Spectre thanks. a typo : )

Comment: a hearty welcome :)

Comment: @OmG: yeah, it can be possible, but think about the cases when $p$ is about greater than $10^{10}$ or $10^{20}$. Very complicated to solve.

Comment: You should point out that the two factors have to have the same parity as they differ by $6x$, which is even.

Comment: @OmG wow... I wonder why *I* didn't think like that... Nice answer and three whistles!!!

Comment: @Matteo It may be arduous, but it's not complicated.  Use a computer.  If $p$ is too large to factor, then the problem is too hard to solve.  You may want to read about factoring algorithms.

Comment: Distinguishing some cases modulo small integers allows you determine precisely when the system has solutions. In many cases there are no solutions. When there are solutions, finding them all is equivalent to factoring $p$.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:** Compute the remainder of $p$ modulo $36$.

1. If $p\equiv2,3,5,6,8,10,11,12,14,15,17,18,20,21,22,23,24,26,29,30,32,33,34,35\pmod{36}$, then there are no solutions.
2. If $p\equiv9,27\pmod{36}$ then for every factorization $p=9uv$ into positive integers $u$ and $v$ with $u>v$ take
   $$x=\frac{u-v}{2}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad y=3\frac{u+v}{2}.$$
3. If $p\equiv0\pmod{36}$ then for every factorization $p=36uv$ into positive integers $u$ and $v$ with $u>v$ take
   $$x=u-v\qquad\text{ and }\qquad y=3(u+v).$$
4. If $p\equiv1,7,13,19,25,31\pmod{36}$ then for every factorization $p=uv$ into positive integers $u$ and $v$ with $u>v$ take
   $$x=\frac{u-v}{6}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad y=\frac{u+v}{2}.$$
5. If $p\equiv4,16,28\pmod{36}$, all solutions $(x,y)$ are of the form $(2x',2y')$ where $(x',y')$ is a solution for $p'=\tfrac p4$.

**Explanation:**

Let $p$ be a large integer. We want to find all positive integers $x$ and $y$ such that
$$9x^2+p=y^2.\tag{1}$$
First note that there are no solutions if $p\equiv2\pmod{3}$ or $p\equiv2\pmod{4}$.

If $p$ is divisible by $3$, which is easy to check given the decimal representation of $p$, then also $y$ is divisible by $3$. Then $y=3z$ for some positive integer $z$ and so
$$p=y^2-9x^2=9z^2-9x^2=9(x^2-z^2),$$
which shows that $p$ must be divisible by $9$. That is to say, if $p\equiv3,6\pmod{9}$ then there are no solutions. Write $p=9q$ to see that
$$q=z^2-x^2=(z+x)(z-x),\tag{2}$$
and so the integers $x$ and $y$ in $(1)$ yield a factorization of $q$ into two factors that are congruent mod $2$. This is of course impossible if $q\equiv2\pmod{4}$, which shows that there are no solutions if $p\equiv6\pmod{12}$. Otherwise, if $q$ is odd then for every factorization $q=uv$ into positive integers $u$ and $v$ with $u>v$ the pair
$$z=\frac{u+v}{2}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad x=\frac{u-v}{2},$$
yields a solution to $(2)$. Similarly, if $q\equiv0\pmod{4}$ then for every factorization $q=4uv$ into positive integers $u$ and $v$ with $u>v$ the pair
$$z=u+v\qquad\text{ and }\qquad x=u-v,$$
yields a solution to $(2)$. Either way we see that:

1. If $p\equiv2\pmod{3}$ or $p\equiv3,6\pmod{9}$ or $p\equiv 6\pmod{12}$, or equivalently $$p\equiv2,3,5,6,8,11,12,14,15,17,18,20,21,23,24,26,29,30,32,33,35\pmod{36},$$ then there are no solutions.
2. If $p\equiv0,9,27\pmod{36}$ then finding all solutions is equivalent to factoring $p$.

On the other hand, if $p\equiv1\pmod{3}$ and $p\not\equiv2\pmod{4}$ then $p\equiv1,4,7\pmod{12}$.

If $p\equiv4\pmod{12}$ then $p\equiv4\pmod{6}$ and from
$$p=y^2-9x^2=(y+3x)(y-3x),$$
we get a factorization of $p$ into two factors that are congruent modulo $6$. It follows that
$$y+3x,y-3x\equiv2\pmod{6},$$
and so both $x$ and $y$ are even, say $x=2x'$ and $y=2y'$. Then $p$ is divisible by $4$, say $p=4p'$, and we find that
$$9(x')^2+p'=(y')^2,$$
where of course $p'\equiv1\pmod3$ because $p\equiv4\pmod{12}$. This shows that every solution $(x,y)$ for $p$ is of the form $(2x',2y')$ where $(x',y')$ is a solution for $p'=\tfrac p4$.

What remains are the cases $p\equiv1,7\pmod{12}$, or equivalently the case $p\equiv1\pmod{6}$. If $p\equiv1\pmod{6}$ then for every factorization $p=uv$ into positive integers $u$ and $v$ with $u>v$ we have $u\equiv v\pmod{6}$. Then setting
$$y=\frac{u+v}{2}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad x=\frac{u-v}{6},$$
yields a solution to $(1)$. Conversely, every solution $(x,y)$ to $(1)$ yields a factorization
$$p=(y+3x)(y-3x),$$
into distinct factors that are congruent modulo $6$. So in this case the problem is again equivalent to factoring $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as per your request, I'd add an answer so the comments section is clear (sorry again for the inconvenience).

Notice that you can rearrange the equation as $p = (y + 3x)(y-3x)$.
The least bound for $p$ is $10^9$ as per your question, so I'd always suggest starting an exhaustive search (due to my being a rookie/ newbie at such big problems) from there so that you can get the least possible $p, x$ and $y$ that satisfies your equation. From there, tactically plan how you can manipulate the value of $x$ and $y$ and still obtain values for $p$. For example, you can add a $9a^2 \pm 6ax$ or $a^2 \pm 2ay$ (I'd suggest going for $9a^2 + 18ax$ or $a^2+ 2ay$ as long as you don't override a solution during the exhaustive search) to both sides of the equation and see the changes yourself.

If you're looking for multiple solutions for the same $p$, you can exchange things around.

##### Edit : OmG's answer is worth a special mention, please go check it above.

##### Edit: Another great contribution by Servaes; please go check below

Answer (score 0):

An experimental approach:

Here I find one solution for this equation which a family of solutions can be based on:

$9x^2=y^2-p=(y-\sqrt p)(y+\sqrt p)$

we can can construct following system of equations:

$\begin{cases}y-\sqrt p=9\\y+\sqrt p=x^2\end{cases}$

Subtracting first equation from second one we get:

$2\sqrt p=x^2-9=(x-3)(x+3)$

Suppose:

$x-3=2\Rightarrow x=5$

$x+3=\sqrt p$

subtracting first fro, second we get:

$\sqrt p-2=6\Rightarrow \sqrt p=8\rightarrow  p=64$

Now we have:

$9x^2=y^2-64=(y-8)(y+8)$

Let $y-8=9\rightarrow y=17$

$x^2=y+8=25$

hence :

$x=5$, $y=17$ and $p=64$

$9\times5^2+64=17^2\space\space\space\space\space (1)$

$10^{12}\div 64=15625\times10^6>10^9$

So we can construct following relation by multiplying both sides of the relation (1) by $15625\times 10^6=(125\times 10^3)^2$:

$9(5\times 125000)^2+15625\times 10^6=(17\times125000)^2$

that is one solution of equation under condition $p=15625000000>10^9$ is:

$x=625\times10^3$

$y=2125\times 10^3$

This experiment shows that only with particular values of p the equation may have integer solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If we let $\quad  A^2+B^2=C^2
\qquad A=3x\quad B=\sqrt{p}\quad C=y\qquad$
we can use Euclid's formula for Pythagorean triples to find infinite solutions based on the value of $(x)$.  We start with the formula

$$ \qquad A=m^2-k^2\qquad B=2mk \qquad C=m^2+k^2\qquad$$
and solve the $A$-function for $(k).\quad$
Then we test a defined range of $m$-values to see which yield integers.

\begin{equation}
A=m^2-k^2\implies k=\sqrt{m^2-A}\\
\text{for}\qquad  \lfloor\sqrt{A+1}\rfloor \le m \le \frac{A+1}{2}
\end{equation}
The lower limit ensures $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and the upper limit ensures $m> k.$

There are Pythagorean triples for all $A=2n+1$ but A=$3x$,  so we are limited to odd muliples of $3:$
$$ x\in\big\{1,3,5,7,\cdots\big\}\implies
A\in\big\{3,9,15,21,\cdots\big\}.\quad $$

Here, we will use $x=5\implies A=15$

$$A=15\implies \lfloor\sqrt{15+1}\rfloor=4\le m \le \frac{15+1}{2} =8\\
\land\quad m\in\{4,8\}\implies k \in\{1,7\} $$
$$F(4,1)=(15,8,17)\implies (x,p,y)=(5,8^2,17)\\
 F(8,7)=(15,112,113)\implies (x,p,y)=(5,112^2,113) $$